# Node/express not finding my app when I type NPM start

Tags: node.js

I am trying node.js for the first time and having some teething problems. I have installed express at w:/nodejs/app/animaltest/package.json. the app is called 'animalTest'

```
{
  "name": "animalTest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "hjs": "~0.0.6",
    "less-middleware": "1.0.x"
  }
}
```

When I try to launch the app by typing 'npm start' I get the following error from the command prompt. Is there a reference for errors? for instance 'not OK code 0' isn't very helpful.

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'W:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'W:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.32
4 verbose node symlink W:\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info prestart animalTest@0.0.0
7 info start animalTest@0.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info animalTest@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
10 error animalTest@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
10 error Exit status 8
11 error Failed at the animalTest@0.0.0 start script.
11 error This is most likely a problem with the animalTest package,
11 error not with npm itself.
11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
11 error     node ./bin/www
11 error You can get their info via:
11 error     npm owner ls animalTest
11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
12 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error command "W:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "W:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error cwd W:\nodejs\app\animalTest
15 error node -v v0.10.32
16 error npm -v 1.4.28
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Please show your package.json. Also, are you sure the express package is in the node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes express is located in the node_modules folder in my animalTest (app name)directory.

Comment: Well, the issue is happening when you run 'node ./bin/www'. Try running it directly in a command line to see what happens. Also, if `www` is a JavaScript file, you must include the file extension.

Comment: If locate the www file in the cmd prompt manually and type 'node www' my express app loads correctly which is great. If it works this way then do I need to bother if 'node start' doesn't work? Only thing is I have to go into the directory every time I want to load my app.

Comment: Maybe your program only runs properly when the working directory is properly defined. have you tried changing your start script to `cd bin;node www;cd ..`?

Comment: How does that command work? I'm trying it whilst in my express app's base directory but its throwing err module.js 340

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb but what do I replace to .. with?

Comment: You weren't supposed to replace that, `..` points to the parent directory. Your claim was that running `www` while in its location was working, so the `cd` commands would just change the working directory.

Comment: Looks like you're running Node on Windows, which (AFAIK) doesn't use *forward* slashes as directory separator. Try this for your start command: `node bin\\www`

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit package.json to reflect the location of my app: - "start": "node nodejs/app/animalTest/bin/www" to replace the default .bin/www

To initialise the app I had to type npm start only when I was in the animalTest directory in the command prompt

Thanks to those people that commented.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by editing the `bin\www` file.
This problem only appears for Windows not for Mac or Linux.

You simply have to remove the crunchbang `#!/usr/bin/env node` in the first line.

I hope this solves your problem.